# Uploading existing database through Plesk

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, web-hosting, plesk

I was trying to upload the database of my ASP.NET website. On the local machine, if I copy the database from another machine, I have to attach it through SQL Server Management Studio and then use it in the connection string like

```
<add name="cn" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

My database is approx. 10 MB in size for now. If I upload it via ftp to App_Data folder, how would I have to attach this database?

In Plesk, I have the option to create the database and its user (as shown in the screenshots):

1) Web Applications and services-Plesk
[image]

2) Add New Database
[image]
and add new database user

3) Webadmin>ASP.ET Enterprise Manager
[image]

But this is for the new database I created. My problem is to upload an existing one.

There's also a section in Plesk for ASP.NET settings (as shown below)
[image]
This has the option to change the connection string etc.

I also asked my hosting provider about the method to be followed for attaching the database that I would upload. This was the reply in quote.

> mdf ldf files perhaps will be working
>   at your local computer but this way
>   database of mssql will not work on web
>   server as on web server you will be
>   required to create and restore your
>   database backup file using plesk
>   control panel.
>
> Sample connection string for asp.net
>   mssql `Standard Security`:
>   "`Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data
>   Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial
>   Catalog=
>   Your_Database_Name;UserId=Your_Username;Password=Your_Password;`"
>
> Server name to be used in coding:
>   localhost Catalog/ database name ,
>   database user and database password
>   you will be required to create your
>   own using plesk control panel"[/quote]

I would be really be appreciative for the steps I have to take to upload my existing database. How do I have attach it? What connection string I have to use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run a sql script on your "new" database in Plesk? If so, you can script the object creation and data in your existing db and execute it thusly. In SSMS:

1. Right click db.
2. Tasks...
3. Generate scripts.

Good luck!